# OpenCV2 Python and time.sleep() - Can't use time.sleep() properly

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, video, time

The thing is: I want to display an image, play an audio then stop the video capture for N seconds. But it actually goes like this: the software stops the video capture for N seconds and displays the image + the audio.

Any idea how to fix this?

I'm using Tkinter to display the video frame.

Code below:

```
while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1280, 720), fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5)

    video.place(x=326, y=0)        
    video.config(image=imgtk)

    for barcode in decode(frame):
        points = np.array([barcode.polygon], np.int32)
        points = points.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
        if points is not None:
            cv2.imwrite(QR_CODE_IMAGE_PATH, frame)
            is_qr_valid = result.get_result(QR_CODE_IMAGE_PATH)
            if is_qr_valid != TEXT_UNABLE_TO_DECODE_ERROR:
                image = None
                audio = None
                
                ######### HERE THE PROBLEMS BEGIN #########
                if is_qr_valid[0] == RESULT_OK:
                    result_message = "QR valido"
                    audio = 'sound/access_ok2.mp3'
                    print("Playsound: valido")
                    result_image = Image.open('popups/1.jpg')
                    test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(result_image)
                    result_label = tk.Label(image=test)
                    result_label.image = test
                    result_label.place(x=int(750), y=int(735))
                    audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=playsound, args=(audio, ), daemon=True)
                    audio_thread.start()
                else:
                    result_message = "QR non valido"
                    audio = 'sound/access_nok2.mp3'
                    print("Playsound: non valido")
                    result_image = Image.open('popups/2.jpg')
                    test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(result_image)
                    result_label = tk.Label(image=test)
                    result_label.image = test
                    result_label.place(x=int(750), y=int(735))
                    audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=playsound, args=(audio, ), daemon=True)
                    audio_thread.start()
                    
                time.sleep(3)          
                
                break
                
           
               
    # cv2.imshow(FRAME_TITLE, frame)
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27: # ESC
        break
    
    # time.sleep(5)
    # cv2.imwrite("qr/qrcode.png", frame)
    # break
    
    window.update()
```

I also tried using cv2.waitKey(N) time.sleep(N) instead of time.sleep(N) but it gives the same result.

How it should be:

1. Displays the image
2. Plays the sounds
3. Stops for N seconds

How it goes:

1. Stops for N seconds
2. Displays the image
3. Plays the sound

Thanks in advance

Comment: provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: read that link.